# How to put a text, shifted to the right into the customized \section

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% no line in header area
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%section with predefined text
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{1}
  \begin{center}\Large{\bf{Problem N \arabic{section}}}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\fancyhead[HR]{Variant 1}
\section{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to achieve the same effect without using any extra packages:

1. Shift the text "Variant 1" to the right of the page, aligning it by the text right border.
2. Keep it at the same line with "Problem N"?

Comment: You can use `\let\sectionorig\section
\let\thesection\relax
\def\section#1{%
   \sectionorig[#1]{\rlap{\centerline{\Large{\bfseries{Problem N \arabic{section}}}}}\hfill#1}%
}` However `\let\thesection\relax` is a ugly hack.

Comment: Note that `\bf` is a TeX command that should not be used in LaTeX. Instead use the `\bseries` declaration or the `\textbf{...}` command.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel No,it's bad. It produced italic capitalized "Variant 1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; the argument for `\section` can be used to write the text flushed to the right margin:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}
  {\hfill Problem N~\thesection\hfill\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont\small#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Variant 1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible leave the right margin after 'Variant 1', so it would be aligned by the right border of the text? 
My intention was not to use any extra packages, cause I thought, that such a simple task could be achieved without them.

Comment: @user4035 Ah, now I see what you want.

Comment: @user4035 please see my updated answer.

Comment: I updated my question too, to make more clear what I need.

Comment: @user4035 Am I missing something? I thought my updated answer was doing exactly what you needed. Please let me know if perhaps my answer is missing anything.

Comment: You are using titlesec package. Is it possible to get rid of it?

Comment: @user4035 It's possible, yes, but certainly will require more work. May I ask you why don't you want to use titlesec?

Comment: Well, it was just programmers perfectionism. Trying to use as little resources as possible. Ok, I don't want to consume your time any more. I'll accept it. Maybe, later you'll find a solution without extra packages.